# Git repo on usb disk. Do I need to move .gitignore to the usb too?

Tags: git, usb

I've moved a git repo (currently in use with remote url) to a usb stick. Do I need to move my global `.gitconfig` file to the usb stick too? I guess I'm worried that if I work on someone else's computer and then push it'll use their config settings.

Comment: .gitignore，.gitconfig， which  do you concern?

Comment: .gitconfig, I keep local .gitignores for each repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global `gitconfig` is under `$HOME`.

You would use "someone else's global `gitconfig`" only if you are logged in as that someone else's account.

That being said, bringing your own global `gitconfig` is a good idea: put it in your `$HOME` once logged in that new computer.